# Ipad UX creating news Board using UIcollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, user-interface, user-experience

I'm new on IOS development and  I'm working on Ipad app for News Blog and I want to create Home screen look like this : [image]

So my question is what's the best way to do that?

- I mean, Should I create reusable view  ( two views : one for the big size
  post and the second for the small size post), then I add those view to my UIViewController in storyboard.
- Or, create one reusable view with the big size and when I added it to storyboard I resize it (I'm not sure if this solution can be achieved and create UIview with dynamic size )?
- Or, I create those view directly in my storyBoard and no need for using reusable component ?

**Update** 
Thank's To Larme solution I've used UIcollectionView. But the problem I can't push the two first small row, in red circle, to top of screen and add under them two other small Cell [image]
I want to have 4 small cells on the right big cell

This is my code:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGSize imgSize = CGSizeMake(230, 160);

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        //double the size for the first cell
        imgSize = CGSizeMake(490, 360);
    }
    return imgSize;
}

-(UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5);
}
```

Comment: `UICollectionView` with different sized items?

Comment: I haven't used ´UICollectionView´ .  So your question is confusing?

Comment: Read about `UICollectionView`. That could be exactly what you need.

Comment: I've read about UICollectionView and I created sample project and normally this will be good solution. thank's

Comment: The issue could be about the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` that you may need to subclass.

Comment: @Larme can you explain it more or give me code example ? I can't figure how to do it ?

Comment: It's been a while since I played UICollectionViewLayout. Anyway you should post some of your code. Other may help you.